# Vaadin button click listener error

Tags: compiler-errors, vaadin

I'm trying to make a connection between mysql and vaadin, when implementing the project, I get the following error message:

[image]

**MyUI class:**

```java
import com.vaadin.annotations.Theme;
import com.vaadin.annotations.VaadinServletConfiguration;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinRequest;
import com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet;
import com.vaadin.ui.Button;
import com.vaadin.ui.Label;
import com.vaadin.ui.TextField;
import com.vaadin.ui.UI;
import com.vaadin.ui.VerticalLayout;

@Theme("mytheme")
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest vaadinRequest) {
        final VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();

        final TextField name = new TextField();
        name.setCaption("Type your name here:");

        Button button = new Button("Click Me");
        button.addClickListener(e -> {
            layout.addComponent(new Label("Thanks " + name.getValue() + ", it works!"));
        });

        layout.addComponents(name, button);

        setContent(layout);
    }

    @WebServlet(urlPatterns = "/*", name = "MyUIServlet", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(ui = MyUI.class, productionMode = false)
    public static class MyUIServlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }
}
```

**Connect class:**

```java
import com.vaadin.addon.sqlcontainer.SQLContainer;
import com.vaadin.addon.sqlcontainer.query.QueryDelegate;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.connection.JDBCConnectionPool;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.connection.SimpleJDBCConnectionPool;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class Connect {
     private JDBCConnectionPool connect = null;
    private SQLContainer containe=null;
    public void connects()
    {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connect=  new SimpleJDBCConnectionPool("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver", "jdb:mysql://localhost:3306/quanlysinhvien", "root", "");
            System.out.println("checkok");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Connect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Connect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    TableQuery tq = new TableQuery("user", connect);
    tq.setVersionColumn("username");
        try {
            containe = new SQLContainer((QueryDelegate) (tq));
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Connect.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

**POM:**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>checkConnet</groupId>
    <artifactId>ccs</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>ccs</name>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <vaadin.version>8.3.1</vaadin.version>
        <vaadin.plugin.version>8.3.1</vaadin.plugin.version>
        <jetty.plugin.version>9.3.9.v20160517</jetty.plugin.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <!-- If there are no local customizations, this can also be "fetch" or "cdn" -->
        <vaadin.widgetset.mode>local</vaadin.widgetset.mode>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>vaadin-addons</id>
            <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-server</artifactId>
            <version>7.7.13</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-push</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-client-compiled</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-themes</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.addons</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-sqlcontainer</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.45</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                    <!-- Exclude an unnecessary file generated by the GWT compiler. -->
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes/VAADIN/widgetsets/WEB-INF/**</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>update-theme</goal>
                            <goal>update-widgetset</goal>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <!-- Comment out compile-theme goal to use on-the-fly theme compilation -->
                            <goal>compile-theme</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <runTarget>http://localhost:8080/ccs</runTarget>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <!-- Clean up also any pre-compiled themes -->
                <configuration>
                    <filesets>
                        <fileset>
                            <directory>src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/styles.css</include>
                                <include>**/styles.scss.cache</include>
                            </includes>
                        </fileset>
                    </filesets>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!-- The Jetty plugin allows us to easily test the development build by
                running jetty:run on the command line. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jetty.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>2</scanIntervalSeconds>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Vaadin pre-release repositories -->
            <id>vaadin-prerelease</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>

            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-prereleases</id>
                    <url>http://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-prereleases</url>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <id>vaadin-snapshots</id>
                    <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/vaadin-snapshots/</url>
                    <releases>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </releases>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>true</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

---

Edit note: the above sources were extracted from the [initial archive OP linked on google drive](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VlcOAiZ1ecYY6SYT6fNBi0IpspVHIJpa)

Comment: Please include the relevant code and the error message here

Comment: you click enter image description here then show full and click link https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VlcOAiZ1ecYY6SYT6fNBi0IpspVHIJpa you have full code because I do not know how to insert my code,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and there is also a help link on each page.

Comment: What does this error in image has to do with mysql connection?

Comment: you can click  "enter image description here" in the my post then it show my messager errors

Comment: Possibly because you're specifying `<version>7.7.13</version>` for the `vaadin-server` dependency while trying to use `<vaadin.version>8.3.1</vaadin.version>`.

Answer (score 3):

The main issue is that you're **trying to mix modules from 2 different Vaadin versions, `8.3.1` & `7.7.13`**, and there are substantial changes between them. Although somehow magically during compile time everything looks fine, at run-time the [expected `addClickListener` method can't be found](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NoSuchMethodError.html)

Initially I thought maybe it was an honest mistake, but then I noticed your `Connect` class is importing stuff from v7:

```
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.connection.JDBCConnectionPool;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.connection.SimpleJDBCConnectionPool;
import com.vaadin.data.util.sqlcontainer.query.TableQuery;
```

You have to decide on a version that you want to use, and import only modules from that version. Then, depending on your projects constraints (eg: no spring, no jpa, vaadin 7, etc), you can check for tutorials on how to hook up your app to MySQL, eg:

- https://spring.io/guides/gs/crud-with-vaadin/ [spring boot, spring data & jpa]
- https://vaadin.com/blog/building-a-web-ui-for-mysql-databases-in-plain-java- [spring boot & spring jdbc template]

The spring examples are a good place to start learning as they require minimum configuration and you don't have to reinvent the wheel via connection pools & such. But like I said, depending on you constraints pick an appropriate tutorial.

**P.S.** After making the changes, be sure to run a `mvn clean` before running you project so there are no old artifacts interfering...